# Is is possible to set the buffer size with mediaelement.js?

Tags: mediaelement.js

Is it possible to set a larger buffer size with mediaelement.js?

The idea would be to experiment with trading off a smoother playback at the cost of a slightly longer startup time,or visa versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the current implementation of MEJS.

Comment: Hi, a lot of time has passed since this reply and now we are at version 2.23.2 of MEJS. Did things change with newer versions ? We run a streaming company and we are finding hard to tune the streaming in different scenarios cause it seems we have 1Gbit uplink on the server side and Red5 started with High Performance optimization and still we have 0 frames dropped, but low quality video... having the possibility to tune the buffer size in MEJS can enable further testing which can help us finding the correct tune.

Comment: @KRiSh05 - I think the original question and answer still stand, but ABR has opened new ways to achieve a similar end in some cases. I've added an answer to capture this also.

Answer (score 0):

As time has passed and Adaptive Bir Rate (ABR) streaming has become much more common, I think it is worth updating to say that while the original question is still valid, ABR provides a method to allow quicker startup at the cost of video quality, or slower startup and better quality.

ABR format streaming essentially means that there is not just a single bit rate.

Multiple bit rate versions of the video are created and each one is broken down into equal length (by time) chunks - e.g. 10 second chunks.

The client player is then able to select the next chunk from the most appropriate bit rate stream for the current network conditions - if the network gets busy it can drop down to a lower bit rate for the next chunk and visa versa if the network is good.

It also allows a video to start more quickly by selecting a low bit rate initially and then to step up to higher bit rates, network conditions allowing, once the video is playing.

You can see a visualisation of the bit rate steps on YouTube by right clicking and looking at the 'stats for nerds' option - see example below:

[image]

You can also see the available bit rates, and force the player to select a single one by clicking on the 'wheel' in the bottom right hand corner.